# BASS library: playing from memory

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bass

I am attempting to play sound clip held in a MemStream: TMemoryStream using the BASS dll. I can read it from a wav file and it plays OK, but I want to get it to read the memory stream directly.

I have initialized the sound device on FormCreate

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject;  
begin  
SafeLoadLibrary ('bass.dll');      //load the bass dll
BASS_Init(-1, 22050, BASS_DEVICE_16BITS, Form1.Handle, nil);   //Initialize an output device
end;
```

Then I create a sine wave in a memory stream and add the .WAV header so the memory stream contains the sound in the correct format:

```
MemStream := WriteWAVFromStream(MemStream, SAMPLERATE, BITSPERSAMPLE);
MemStream.Position := 0;
```

Then I try get the stream to play using BASS:

```
var
ch: HSTREAM;
P: ^TMemoryStream;

P := @MemStream;
ch := BASS_StreamCreateFile(TRUE, P, 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_AUTOFREE);
BASS_ChannelPlay(ch, False);

finally
Memstream.Free;
```

Any ideas why BASS won't play the memstream?

Comment: You are giving bass the address of a Delphi `TMemoryStream` object. Are you sure you are supposed to do that? I don't think BASS knows anything about such Delphi classes. I think the library would prefer a pointer to the actual waveform audio data managed by the `TMemoryStream` object: `MemStream.Memory`.

Comment: Also note this warning in the [documentation](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_StreamCreateFile.html): "*When streaming from memory (mem = TRUE), the memory must not be freed before the stream is freed.*"

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You are giving BASS the address of a Delphi `TMemoryStream` object. Are you sure you are supposed to do that? I don't think BASS knows anything about such Delphi classes.

Instead, the library probably expects a pointer to the actual waveform audio data managed by the `TMemoryStream` object: `MemStream.Memory`.

Comment: Thanks. I have it working now. I needed to add the MemStream.memory and size of the stream by MemStream.size:  channel := BASS_StreamCreateFile(true, MemStream.Memory, 0, memstream.Size, BASS_STREAM_AUTOFREE);
           BASS_ChannelPlay(channel, False);